# How to bind jsGrid from SQL Server

Tags: c#, jsgrid

I am using `jsGrid` (**Grid jQuery Plugin**) to display data in tabular format,below is the code that i have

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "70%",
            width: "100%",
            filtering: true,
            editing: true,
            inserting: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,
            pageSize: 15,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",
            controller: db,
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
                { name: "Country", type: "select", items: db.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
                { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

It Take data either from a service or from a file which is `db.js` as follow

```
db.countries = [
    { Name: "", Id: 0 },
    { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
    { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
    { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 },
    { Name: "France", Id: 4 },
    { Name: "Brazil", Id: 5 },
    { Name: "China", Id: 6 },
    { Name: "Russia", Id: 7 }
];

db.clients = [
    {
        "Name": "Otto Clay",
        "Age": 61,
        "Country": 6,
        "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue",
        "Married": false
    },
    {
        "Name": "Connor Johnston",
        "Age": 73,
        "Country": 7,
        "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.",
        "Married": false
    },
    {
        "Name": "Lacey Hess",
        "Age": 29,
        "Country": 7,
        "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.",
        "Married": false
    }];
```

I want to pass data into it from a data source like MS SQL Server , How can we do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your grid work with the above static data from db.js? If it does, then it's not about jsGrid but more about SQL and web services. Basically, you need to create a web service that queries your SQL database and returns an array of data for your jsGrid.

The call to the web service can be in the `loadData` controller. The [documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller) shows a simple example. Below is a similar example using promises where `/api/data` is the Ajax call to the web service that has to return the data in the form your static file is returning:

```
 ...
 controller: {
   loadData: function(filter) { 
               return $.getJSON("/api/data/"
                ).done(function(results) {
                    console.log(results);
               }).fail(function(err) {
                     alert(err));
                  }); 
     },
 },
 ...
```

You may want to start simple and avoid paging for now to test that getting data works. Paging requires a more complex query that also need to return the total number of records in the result.  From the [documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/#loaddatafilter-promisedataresult):

> **dataResult** depends on `pageLoading`. When `pageLoading` is false (by default), then data result is a plain javascript array of objects. If `pageLoading` is true data result should have following structure:

```
{
   data          // array of items
   itemsCount    // total items amount in storage
}
```

Comment: return $.getJSON("/api/data/"   is it the path to web service like "http://abc/xyz.asmx" ??

Comment: That is correct. To use Ajax, the web service has to be on the same host as your web page. If you use ASMX you may need to convert the data to the Javascript objects needed for jsGrid, eg `[{Name:"...", Age:yy, ...}, {Name:"...", Age:zz, ...}, ...]`.  It's easier if your web service can output `Content-type: application/json`.